# Fill a list from a file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a file which contains words separated by commas like:

```
tom,harry,ant,qqqq
aa,ww,rr,gg,aa,hh,ss
```

I would like to split each element separated by a comma and fill a list like this:

```
array=['tom','harry','ant','qqqq','aa','ww','rr','gg','aa','hh','ss']
```

So far I tried with:

```
array=list()

for i in open(filename):
    element = i.split(',',len(i))
    array.append(element)
```

When I print I obtain two problems:

```
for i in array 
    print i
```

I obtain `['tom','harry','ant','qqqq\n']` and `['qqqq','aa','ww','rr','gg','aa','hh','ss\n']`

I would like to avoid the `\n` and to have a unique list as said before

Comment: Use `element = i[:-1].split(',',len(i))` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    array = myFile.read().replace('\n', ',').split(',')

for i in array:
    print i
```

One liner:

```
with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as myFile: array = myFile.read().replace('\n', ',').split(',')
```

You should also avoid using names like array, list etc when assigning values. It's bad practice.

If you have any other questions send me a pm!

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the line first to avoid the `\n`, and use `extend` instead of `append`:

```
for i in open(filename):
    line = i.strip()
    element = line.split(',')
    array.extend(element)
```

Extend is used to add the elements to your array, instead of adding the array itself. The result would be:

```
['tom','harry','ant','qqqq','aa','ww','rr','gg','aa','hh','ss']
```

Instead of:

```
[['tom','harry','ant','qqqq'], ['aa','ww','rr','gg','aa','hh','ss']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like a comma separated file, i recommend you to use [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

```
import csv
with open('file') as f:
    csv_file = csv.reader(f)
    L = []
    for i in csv_file:
        L.append(i)
    print [i for j in L for i in j]
```

Output:

```
['tom', 'harry', 'ant', 'qqqq', 'aa', 'ww', 'rr', 'gg', 'aa', 'hh', 'ss']
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating file yield lines with newline. Strip the newline explicitly:

By Replacing following line:

```
element = i.split(',',len(i))
```

with:

```
element = i.rstrip().split(',',len(i))  # Remove trailing space charcters.
```

or

```
element = i.rstrip('\r\n').split(',',len(i))  # Remove CR / LF.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"[,\n]+", open(filename).read())
['tom', 'harry', 'ant', 'qqqq', 'aa', 'ww', 'rr', 'gg', 'aa', 'hh', 'ss']
```